# Run a custom npm script with PM2

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, pm2

I am currently developing several Telegram bots but I want to keep all of them in the same git repository. The issue is that on the other hand, I want to run them as separate processes.

Since I'm using the Telegraf framework, to run a bot it goes such as: `micro-bot src/bot-one/bot.js`

The problem comes when doing this with PM2. I've been able to run one of the bots with the `npm start` script like this:

```
pm2 start --name "WeatherBot" npm -- start -- -t <
TOKEN>
```

But I'd like to be able to create custom scripts like this:

```
"main": "src/weatherWarnBot/bot.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "micro-bot",
    "littleAppleBot": "micro-bot src/littleAppleBot/bot.js",
    "weatherWarnBot": "micro-bot src/weatherWarnBot/bot.js"
}
```

But, how would the PM2 command be to run each of the two custom scripts? I was thinking of having the bot tokens set as enviroment variables of the system, for simplification.

Comment: Did you try `npm run littleAppleBot`?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou The thing is I would like to do it through it PM2 to have the process running in the background

Comment: Yes I mean put npm run into pm2 command. Like `pm2 start npm -- run littleAppleBot --`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

`pm2 start npm -- run littleAppleBot --`

`pm2 start npm -- run weatherWarnBot --`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :) The whole command was: `pm2 start --name "LittleAppleBot"  npm -- run littleAppleBot -- -t <TOKEN>`

Comment: I am glad it is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Use this :-

`pm2 start --name "Script Name" npm -- run <YOUR CUSTOM SCRIPT> --`

Answer (score 2):

```
pm2 start npm --name "Your APP Name" -- start
```

Answer (score 0):

how bout this:

```
pm2 start "micro-bot src/bot-one/bot.js"
```