# Run custom script using PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I tried using this question's answer ([Run a custom npm script with PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307402/run-a-custom-npm-script-with-pm2)), but it's not working for me.
I have a folder called 'frontend' and I want to start the 'dev' script inside it, but it keeps starting the default 'start' script.
Some of my tries:

- pm2 start frontend -- run dev --
- pm2 start frontend -- run dev
- pm2 start npm --name=frontend -- dev
- pm2 start npm --name=frontend -- run dev

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order is different :-)

what `--` does is, it pipes the arguments righthand of `--` to the left hand.

**First you need to go to that frontend folder where(or wherever) package.json is located then,**

```
pm2 start npm -- run dev
```

`pm2 start` starts the process.
`npm` here means you want to start the `npm` command.
`-- run dev` means `run dev` is piped to `npm`. So basically you are running, `pm2 start (npm run dev)`

If you want to add process name add it BEFORE `npm`:

```
pm2 start --name="MyPRocess" npm -- run dev
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind! Actually I needed this to run 'ng serve', I tried now like: pm2 start ng -- run serve but this didn't work. Anyway I ended up just cding into the folder and running 'ng serve'. I only need this just for development, so that's not a big deal.